# creating an object based on some conditions in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model called `Showcase` that users use to showcase projects. I am trying to implement a case where any administrator in the `Administrators` field in the showcase can add collaborators through the `Collaborator` model. When I run my code below, I get

`IntegrityError at /api/showcase/the-gods-must-be-crazy-zz2fox/collaborator/create/
NOT NULL constraint failed: showcase_collaborator.user_id`.

models.py

```
class Showcase(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    skill_type = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="Showcases")
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="upvotes")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    administrator = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="administrators", blank=True)


class Collaborator(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Showcase, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="collaborated_showcases")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="collaborators")
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="creative_type")
    role = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

serializer

```
class CollaboratorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='slug')

    class Meta:
        model = Collaborator
        exclude = ['created_on', 'updated_on']

class ShowcaseAdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    administrator = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='slug', many=True, queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Showcase
        fields = ['administrator',]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        users = validated_data.get('administrator')
        for user in users:
            instance.administrator.add(user)
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class collaboratorCreateView(APIView):
    '''
    add collaborator to a showcase
    '''
    serializer_class = CollaboratorSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdmin]

    def post(self, request, slug):
        showcase = get_object_or_404(Showcase, slug=slug)

        try:
            self.check_object_permissions(request, showcase)
            collaborator = Collaborator.objects.create(
                post = showcase
            )
            serializer = self.serializer_class(collaborator, data=request.data, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except APIException:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

URLs

```
path("<slug:slug>/collaborator/create/", qv.collaboratorCreateView.as_view(), name="add-collaborator-to-showcase"),
```

also, as an extra, I was wondering how to prevent creating a duplicate user as a collaborator if possible. I am guessing an if statement MIGHT solve the problem, but I am lost about that because I don't know how to get user input to check in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error said, you need to provide value for `user` attribute in model here. So you can do it like this.

First, update the serializer:

```
class CollaboratorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='slug')

    class Meta:
        model = Collaborator
        exclude = ['created_on', 'updated_on', 'user']

    def validate_user(self, value):
        showcase = self.context.get('post')
        if showcase.collaborated_showcases.filter(user=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Can't add an existing collaborator to a showcase")
        return value

   def create(self, validated_data):
       validated_data['post'] = self.context['post']
       return super(CollaboratorSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Then update the view:

```
class collaboratorCreateView(APIView):
    '''
    add collaborator to a showcase
    '''
    serializer_class = CollaboratorSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdmin]

    def post(self, request, slug):
        showcase = get_object_or_404(Showcase, slug=slug)

        try:
            self.check_object_permissions(request, showcase)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'post':showcase})
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
```

Here I am passing the `showcase` object to Collaborator via [**`context`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context).

Comment: For that, you need to add validation methods: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation please see the updated answer

Comment: Bro, there are two problems   1) the user is important as we are adding them as a collaborator to the showcase, therefore excluding them would be an issue    2) I eventually excluded them and ran into an error, if I also try the normal way excluding them, the user field is blank

Comment: the error I get is, ```create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: Bro, please the very last help I need, please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199608/combining-2-custom-permissions-in-django-rest-framework