# Combining 2 custom permissions in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model called `Showcase` that users use to showcase projects, and also a collaboration model where users can add collaborators to the showcase. I am trying to implement a case where administrators in the showcase and the user in a collaboration can delete that collaboration.

To explain better, in a showcase model, there is a list of administrators that manage the showcase. they also can add collaborators (through the `Collaborator` model) to a showcase. The `Collaborator` has a user field which is the user contributed to the showcase.

I want that after a collaborator has been added, that user can either delete himself (in a case he doesnt want to be part of the showcase) or the administrators can delete that collaborator (in a case thay added a wrong user and want to delete him from that showcase)

models.py

```
class Showcase(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    skill_type = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="Showcases")
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="upvotes")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    administrator = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="administrators", blank=True)


class Collaborator(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Showcase, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="collaborated_showcases")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="collaborators")
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="creative_type")
    role = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

permission.py

```
class IsUser(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return False
        return obj.user == request.user


class IsAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return False
        return request.user.administrators.filter(pk=obj.pk).exists()
```

view.py

```
class CollaboratorDeleteView(APIView):
    '''
    Allow Administrators to delete a collaborator to a showcase 
    or allow the collaborator user to be able to delete himself 
    '''
    permission_classes = [IsAdmin]

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        collaborator = get_object_or_404(Collaborator, pk=pk)
        showcase = collaborator.post

        try:
            self.check_object_permissions(request, showcase)
            collaborator.delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        except APIException:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

URLs

```
path("collaborator/<int:pk>/delete/", qv.CollaboratorDeleteView.as_view(), name="collaborator-delete-view"),
```

Right now I have been able to implement that administrators can remove the collaborator, but how can I add another permission for the user in the `Collaborator` model to be able to delete himself as a collaborator through that same view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually both permissions can be combined into single one. For example updating the permission like this:

```
class CanDeleteUser(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return False
        return obj.user == request.user or ob.post.administrator.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists()
```

Here I am checking either the `request.user` is `obj.user` or checking against administrators of the `showcase` object attached with `obj` variable.

Now I am only going to check permission for `collaborator`.

```
class CollaboratorDeleteView(APIView):
    '''
    Allow Administrators to delete a collaborator to a showcase 
    or allow the collaborator user to be able to delete himself 
    '''
    permission_classes = [CanDeleteUser]

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        collaborator = get_object_or_404(Collaborator, pk=pk)

        try:
            self.check_object_permissions(request, collaborator)
```

Comment: This did it for me, Thank you once again. You are a legend

Comment: Bro, please can you once again check out an issue I have been stuck with for weeks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218433/allauth-unverified-email-remains-unverified-once-email-expires    please I would really appreciate it if you could help.

Answer (score 3):

You can add as many permissions as you need to `permission_classses` attribute using & (and), | (or) and ~ (not) signs ([doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy)):

```
class CollaboratorDeleteView(APIView):
    '''
    Allow Administrators to delete a collaborator to a showcase 
    or allow the collaborator user to be able to delete himself 
    '''
    permission_classes = [IsAdmin|IsUser]
```

Both of this permissions will work now with `OR` logic.

Comment: that will not work in this case, in the question you would see I am trying to combine permissions in different models which makes this one different.

Comment: and with this line ```self.check_object_permissions(request, showcase)``` it will not make that possible

Comment: @OpeyemiOdedeyi this should work. Which version of rest framework do you use? This feature available from version 3.9

Comment: good day, yeah normally your solution would work, but what I was working on needed more complex permission. the answer below from @rudda did the trick for me. YNWA.