# allauth unverified email remains unverified once email expires

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I have a custom user model. and I use Django rest auth to handle authentication of users. the **problem** is that after sign up when the email is sent. if the user doesn't verify the email before it expires, it seems that it remains stuck like that indefinitely. I was expecting the verification email to be sent again since `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"` in my settings, from the documentation, it is supposed to resend the verification message by default, but this isnt happening. I am lost as to what else to do and I can't seem to find any resource that helps.

below is my model

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
```

in my **settings.py** the user has an expiry date of 2 days

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = None #or "api/authenticated/"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_HMAC = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "http"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_COOLDOWN = 3600
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 180
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE = True
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_PASSWORD_RESET = False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "api/login/"
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_EMAIL_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I was able to solve this differently, I created a view and URL that requests the user email and then send a link to them if they are unverified.

views.py

```
from allauth.account.utils import send_email_confirmation
from allauth.account.admin import EmailAddress
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException


class EmailConfirmation(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny] 

    def post(self, request):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, email=request.data['email'])
        emailAddress = EmailAddress.objects.filter(user=user, verified=True).exists()

        if emailAddress:
            return Response({'message': 'This email is already verified'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            try:
                send_email_confirmation(request, user=user)
                return Response({'message': 'Email confirmation sent'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except APIException:
                return Response({'message': 'This email does not exist, please create a new account'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

urls.py

```
path('verify-email/again/', qv.EmailConfirmation.as_view(), name='resend-email-confirmation'),
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have mentioned you are using `django-rest-auth` which is not the case, and you are probably using `django-allauth`.

According to `django-allauth`'s documentation:

> **ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION**:
>
> When set to “mandatory” the user is blocked from logging in until the email address is verified. Choose “optional” or “none” to allow logins with an unverified e-mail address. In case of “optional”, the e-mail verification mail is still sent, whereas in case of “none” no e-mail verification mails are sent.

So there is nothing mentioned about re-sending the verification email if the first one expires. To accomplish what you want, you should have a `job` script running and checking for `expired` verification tokens and re-send the verification emails manually.

You should create a script that looks something like this:

```
from time import sleep
from django.utils import timezone
from django_allauth.account.models import EmailConfirmation

while True:
    def_expired = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=app_settings.EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS)
    expired_tokens = EmailConfirmation.objects.filter(sent__lte=def_expired)
    for token in expired_tokens:
        token.send()
    sleep(2)
```

And keep this script running using any scheduler you like (`supervisor`, `pm2`, `cronjob`, etc).

Bottom line, `django-allauth` does not/can not have the functionality you want. This job needs to be done manually.